# how to set a stop loss for a future position in Kucoin using python

Tags: kucoin

kucoin-future api setting stoploss

def set_stoploss(symbol,side,lever,size,price):
try:
return client_trade.create_limit_order(symbol=symbol,side=side,lever=lever, size=size,price=price,reduceOnly =True)
except Exception as e:
print('set_stoploss()::  '+str(e))

Comment: Please read: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)